# Ionic Angular js IDE

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there an IDE like Xcode to develop cross platform apps using ionic? I played with creator.ionic.io but they charge 40$ per month for the complete app development. Can you suggest some open source IDEs? Basically I wanted something similar to ionic where I can drag and drop objects to build the UI

Comment: do you need to develop Ionic2 apps or?

Comment: Yes. To develop cross platform apps

Comment: I asked `Ionic1` or `Ionic2`?

Comment: Sorry, ionic 2. If there is something for ionic 1, that should be fine as well

Comment: The community here is now on confused mood.can you give your feedback?@Nagavardhan Venkata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think community gets totally confused about the OP's question here.He is asking not about an IDE for developing Ionic apps.He is asking the IDE like an [**Ionic creator**](http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/getting-started).Which is the IDE anyone can create ionic apps without writing a code.

**What is an Ionic Creator?** [**See here.**](http://ionic.io/products/creator)

> Creator is a simple drag-&-drop tool for going from  idea to App
>   Store, with just the drag of a mouse.

There is **no** such free and open source tool but the price you have mentioned is not correct with the official Ionic creator. It is $24/mo.You can see [**details here**](http://ionic.io/products/creator/pricing).

> PRO
>
> - $24/mo for individuals
> - Unlimited Projects
> - Private Projects
> - In-Tool Code Editing
> - Basic & Native Exporting
> - Creator Mobile App

**Note:**

By using above tool you can create Ionic 1 apps only.There is no support for Ionic 2 yet. You can see the [**Roadmap of Ionic 2 creator here**](http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/ionic-2-support-roadmap).

Answer (score 3):

I had come across the same problem when i started at first and found some suggestions from ionic official website.

I copied contents here for convenience.

**Visual Studio Code**

VS Code is a new editor that comes with support for ES6 syntax, as well as TypeScript support. It will also prompt users to include TypeScript definition files and download them from Definitely Typed. Visual Studio Code is free and works on OS X, Windows, and Linux.

**Atom**

Atom is cross platform editor built on web technologies. Atom has many plugins to make ES6/TypeScript development very easy. If there isn't something provided by Atom or a plugin, you can even make a plugin yourself, using JavaScript. Atom works on OS X, Windows, and Linux.

**WebStorm**

WebStorm is a paid IDE that provides many features, such as advanced refactoring support, automatic compilation of code, and gulp/grunt/webpack support. Out of the box, WebStorm comes with support for ES6 and TypeScript, as well as Angular and Ionic syntax support.

ALM

ALM is a free open source IDE built for typescript development, it can be run on any computer running chrome and can be hosted on a server and used on any computer with internet access.

**Angular IDE by Webclipse**

Angular IDE is a freemium IDE built for Angular 2 and TypeScript development providing integrated terminal support helping with node and npm management. Out of the box, Angular IDE includes code completion and validation for ES6, TypeScript, and Angular 2 HTML templates.

Personally i am using "**Brackets**" its open source as well and really good.